# How does one obtain the "black" camo in BF3?

Tags: battlefield-3

Playing around in Battlefield 3 I often see players (with a rank higher or equal to 42, I noticed) that wear a black suit that's very difficult to spot (i.e. a relatively long time and short distance before the orange triangle appears over the player's head).

Is it part of some expansion or does one obtain such camo at some rank? I can't find any clue about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spec Ops camo is unlocked at level 42.

It doesn't have the special properties you listed (that being harder to spot for your teammates) it does however have the special property of making you harder to see if your enemy is using an IRNV scope.

While wearing it, the black parts of your camo (not your gun or the ammo pouches etc.) will not show any heat through an IRNV scope.

Comment: Ah, ok! I was convinced of that particular behaviour because I really perceived an increased difficulty in marking enemies. Evidently I am mistaken and my opponents (casually wearing that camo) are really good players. Thank you!

Comment: Since someone bumped this question - dug around a bit and found out that in addition to level 42, you need to have accumulated 1,400,000 points to unlock the Spec Ops Black Camo.